# zsh: how to change the keybinding for reverse search

Tags: zsh

I have already a program in archlinux called `hstr` which searches for history using `ctrl+r`

now i want to use the `zsh`'s history search which uses `ctrl+r`. Since hstr is already bound to that key, how can i change the `zsh`'s history search to `ctrl+i`

I found `hstr` does not show multiline history properly, thats why i want to use both of them

`hstr` using `ctrl+r` and `zsh`'s using `ctrl+i`

Comment: Maybe: `bindkey '^I' history-incremental-search-backward` - I have not tested this. Note that `^I`/`ctrl+i` is the same character as `tab`, so using that key combination will probably interfere with tab-completion in `zsh`.

Comment: thats what happened, and i was no clue why tab is also behaving like that. thanks

Comment: @Santhosh Since you no longer need an answer, can you please close your question? Then it won't stay on the list of unanswered questions. :)